# UK IT professional looking to relocate to CT USA - any tips?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I am a UK citizen, and am an IT professional with approx 20 years experience in IT, I'm now a Systems Architect specialising in BI and Data.

I would like to relocate to the CT/New England area in order to be nearer my (minor) son who moved over to the US 3 years ago after his mother remarried to an american citizen.  Things have been not great for him following his mother being diagnosed with Cancer and he's found the move hard.  So, I figure if I'm over there he's got somewhere to be if things get too much at home - right now, he doesn't have that luxury.

I figure the easiest way is to get over on a H1B visa, but I hear that's riddled with issues and finding an employer is essential.  I'm searching for jobs I could do in the area that are on LinkedIn and other social media - but does anyone have any tips as to how I could improve my chances?  Are there other visas that might be appropriate in this instance, eg if I got his Step-dad to sponsor me could that be an option to getting overseas?

Would appreciate any insight.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/usa-immigration-by-a-european-citizen

Comment: His stepfather can't sponsor you for family immigration because you are not a family member of his stepfather.  Only certain family relationships qualify.  The employment angle is probably the best option, even though it's not a particularly good one.

Comment: Thank you both.  Hmmm...the comment by Traveller is an interesting angle, my current employer does have offices in the US (although not in CT, and is sort of a sister company rather than a direct link to my current place of work).

Comment: Is your son a US citizen?

Comment: @Eric no, he is still a minor and classed as a permanent resident, I don't believe his mother has a greencard yet but could be mistaken.